# Getting rid of titles of subtables in the table with subtables

Tags: tables, captions, titles

I might have missed it but I couldn't find the answers in the archive of the previously asked questions. I am trying to make one table with two subtables which each subtable has its own caption with no title. I want the whole set considered as one table in numbering. In other words, in my current code, I want to keep TABLE I. and get rid of TABLE II. and TABLE III. Also, each subtable is counted once which messing up the numerating of the tables.

Thank you,

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}
%\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{amssymb}% Package to draw a square in the formulas
\usepackage{wasysym}% Package to draw a square in the figures
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[t]
    \caption{ Caption for the table. }
    \label{table: DFT}
  \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
     \caption*{Subcaption one} 
      \centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c} 
  Configuration & cell & cell &\\ [.1ex] 
 \hline \hline \\[0.01ex]
cell   & cell & cell& \\
 cell  &  cell  & cell &\\ [.1ex] 
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption*{Subcaption for table II } \label{table: Exp} 
\begin{tabular}{c c c c} 

  &cell & cell & cell \\ [.1ex] 
 \hline\hline \\[0.01ex]
&cell   & cell & cell \\
&cell  & cell   & cell \\ [.1ex] 
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who have same question.I found the answer which comes as follows:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{amssymb}% Package to draw a square in the formulas
\usepackage{wasysym}% Package to draw a square in the figures
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}

\begin{document}

   \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:example}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}  \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-3}
    \cmidrule(l){4-6}
  Class       &  Class       &    Class       & Number    & Class     & Number    \\
    \midrule   
     Class       &  Class       &  aaa        & bbb       & ccc       & ddd       \\  
     Class       &  Class       &  aaa        & bbb       & ccc       & ddd       \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```